# Qt C++ Потоки и ProgressBar

Tags: c++, qt

Всем привет. Есть пулл потоков, к примеру их 10 штук. Как сделать так, что по завершению каждого из потоков идёт прибавка в ProgressBar? К примеру есть 10 элементов, на каждый элемент по потоку итого 100/10 каждое завершение потока +10% к progressBar. Как грамотно сделать такой ProgressBar ?  Код тестового примера ниже:

**Начало всего:**

```
void Calculate::start()
{

QVector<int> elements;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    elements.append(i);
}

QVector<int> KA;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    KA.append(i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < KA.size(); i++)
{
    Worker * worker = new Worker(i);
    worker->setAutoDelete(false);
    worker->setElements(&elements,elements.size());

    QThreadPool *threadPool = QThreadPool::globalInstance();
    threadPool->setMaxThreadCount(KA.size());
    threadPool->start(worker);
}

}
```

**Worker.h**

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QRunnable>

class Worker : public QObject, public QRunnable
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
Worker(int _indexKA);
~Worker();

void setElements(QVector<int> *_elements, int size)
{
    elements = _elements;
    sizeElements = size;
}

virtual void run();

signals:

private:
int indexKA;
QVector<int> *elements;
int sizeElements;

};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

**Worker.cpp**

```
#include "worker.h"
#include <QDebug>

Worker::Worker(int _indexKA)
{
indexKA = _indexKA;
}

Worker::~Worker()
{

}

void Worker::run()
{
qDebug() << "START";

int summ = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeElements; i++)
{
    summ = indexKA + i;
    qDebug() << summ;
}

qDebug() << summ;

// здесь как то уведомить поток о завершении и передать 10% в прогресс бар

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Объявите сигнал о завершении работы воркера (без параметров), этот сигнал принимайте в интерфейсе от каждого из воркеров пула и при поступлении сигнала увеличивайте значение в прогресс-баре на фиксированную величину, рассчитывваемую из количества воркеров. Подразумевается, что количество воркеров известно в том месте, где требуется обновить прогресс-бар.

Сам по себе воркер не должен знать, сколько процентов работы он завершил, так как он ничего не знает о других воркерах.

Comment: Примерно так и сделал уже, но сигнал с параметром int(100/кол-во элементов(столько же и потоков)) и связываю через слот прогресс бара куда посылаются это значение и плюсуется в общую переменную, она выводится в прогресс бар.

Comment: Если каждый воркер всегда знает, сколько у него соседей, и может рассчитать, какой процент общей работы он делает, тогда такой вариант тоже возможен